# Determine over/under of regression prediction

Tags: regression, prediction-interval

I've created a regression analysis in Excel and using the model I have created a prediction point for Y for a given input of X.  I'd like to add an "over/under" to the Y value to show the range that Y could reasonably be expected to fall in.

Is using Y +/- the "standard error value for y" (Sey from the LINEST function) a reasonable approach or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Excel, but you want a [prediction interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval) for an individual observation; not anything based on a standard error, which applies to uncertainty around the expected value.

Comment: Some details of the difference between confidence intervals and prediction intervals for simple regression, and their implementation in Excel are [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/regression/confidence-and-prediction-intervals/).